# Hide Add button From Grid

Tags: acumatica

I would like to completely hide the Add button in a grid (using Acumatica Framework). I know how to disable it using AllowInsert false, but I would like to hide it completely? Is that possible please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that for some reasons you want to hide Add button from Sales Order Details Grid. For achieving this you should do the following:
1. Add Sales Orders screeen to Customization's Screens. You can do it by clicking **Add Screen** -> **Customize Existing Screen** and selecting Sales Orders screen in the appeared Smart Panel.
2. Now you should go to the **Tab**->**Document Details**->**Grid:Transactions** and select **Properties** in the panel on the Right open **Action Bar** -> **Actions**-> **Add New** and set **Enabled** to `false`.

Now publish your customization. As a result you will get the following:

[image]