# Overwrite Add action of a grid

Tags: acumatica

I have a standard Acumatica screen with a Form and a Grid. Is it possible to overwrite the Add Button of a grid, so that I can carry out a custom action rather than using the standard Add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways is to hide the Standard Add New as I have described in the answer [hide-add-button-from-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905465/hide-add-button-from-grid/44908043#44908043) and create your own.
Now you should create PXAction in your Graph with it's corresponding method like this:

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> CustomAddNew;

[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add New")]
protected void customAddNew()
{
    //your code here
}
```

After this you should go to the page and do the following:

1. Add a button to the DataSource to Hide Action from the Action Bar of the Header in this way:
   Where the  Name is your PXAction.
   [image]
2. Add a button to the Grid with the following setting:
   Where
   ImageKey="AddNew" is for setting the Icon
   AutoCallBack.Command="CustomAddNew" is the Name of your PXAction
   DisplayStyle="Image" is for showing only the Icon.
   [image]

As a result you will get the following :
Where the '+' is your PXAction
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed Answer. The only issue I see is that the add button is after the delete (not before it). I don't think there is a way to correct this, right?

Comment: @JosephCaruana I was looking for actions order property, I remember that there must be something like that, but I could not find .

Comment: You can use GroupIndex and Order attributes of action bar element: <px:PXToolBarButton><ActionBar GroupIndex="1" Order="1" />
<AutoCallBack Command="MyCommand" Target="ds" /></px:PXToolBarButton>

Comment: For built in commands, this can be set in the project editor: <Refresh GroupIndex="2" Order="1" />